# users.find is not a function nodejs

Tags: node.js

so i try to implement jwt on my nodejs application.

here is my token method :

```
app.post("/api/v1/token", function(req, res) {  
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        let email = req.body.email;
        let password = req.body.password;
        let user = users.find(function(u) {
            return u.email === email && u.password === password;
        });
        if (user) {
            let payload = {
                id: user.id
            };
            let token = jwt.encode(payload, cfg.jwtSecret);
            res.json({
                id: user.id,
                token: token,
                status:'success'
            });
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});
```

as you can see, i refer it to users module.
and then i find users based on email and password.
it refers to my users js module.

here is my users js module :

```
var users = require('./app/api/users/login.js');
module.exports = users;
```

login js module :

```
const db = require('../../config/db');
const abort = require('../../util/abort');

const ctl = {
  getAllUser(req, res, next) {
    db.any('SELECT * FROM users')
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        throw abort(404, 'No user data yet', 'Empty user table');
      }

      return res.status(200).json([{
        data,
      }]);
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
  },
};

module.exports = ctl;
```

idk why, everytime i try to get the token.
it always return error msg like this : 
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "users.find is not a function"
}

pls help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your login.js module there is no mothod named "find". Try calling a method that exists on it, such as ***getAllUser***.

Comment: no bro, if i update my users module to array of json data, its work perfectly well.

Comment: Is the path to your file correct? What errors do you see in the console?

Answer (score 0):

It gives `users.find is not a function` because `users` in this case isn't an array. `find()` exist only on arrays. You can `console.log(users)` to know what value it was before the error occurred

Inspecting your code further, your seem to return `next(err)` in `login.js`. If you're manually wrapping callback to promise when calling `getAllUser()`, check for any accidental handling of `err` with `users`